# Capture groups not working in Sublime Text RegReplace package

Tags: regex, sublimetext2

This is the original HTML:

```
<td class="danish">newtext</td>
<td><?php audioButton("../../audio/lessons/01/oldtext","oldtext"); ?></td>
<td><?php audioButton("../../audio/lessons/01/slow/oldtext_slx","oldtext_slx","1"); ?></td>
```

I want to replace 'oldtext' with 'newtext' using the RegReplace package in Sublime Text 2.

This is what I have in `reg_replace.sublime-settings` (no need to analyze the whole thing. The point is that it has a few (.*) in it):

```
{
"replacements": {
    "audiobutton_rep": {
                "find": "<td class=\"danish\">(.*)</td>\\n.*<td><\\?php audioButton\\(\"(.*)/.*\",\".*\"\\); \\?></td>\\n.*<td><\\?php audioButton\\(\"(.*)/.*\",\".*\",\"1\"\\);.*\\?></td>",
                "replace": "<td class=\"danish\">$1</td>\n<td><?php audioButton(\"$2/$1\",\"$1\");?></td>\n<td><?php audioButton(\"$3/$1_slx\",\"$1_slx\",\"1\");?></td>",
                "greedy": true,
                "case": false
    },
```

This is the command in `default.sublime-commands`:

```
{
    "caption": "Reg Replace: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "command": "reg_replace",
    "args": {"replacements": ["audiobutton_rep"] }
 },
```

The capture groups don't work, so the output looks like this:

```
<td class="danish">$1</td>
<td><?php audioButton("$2/$1","$1");?></td>
<td><?php audioButton("$3/$1_slx","$1_slx","1");?></td>
```

It works perfectly when I run it on its own, but not here.

Comment: Maybe not very helpful in this case, but still useful to keep in mind: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2224996

Comment: Well OK then :) But it works most of the time. Maybe my luck's finally run out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using `\\1`, `\\2` and `\\3` instead of `$1`, `$2` and `$3`.

Sublime Text's built-in search/replace uses the Boost library, which accepts either `$1` or `\1` in the replacement string, and most other flavors accept only `$1`.  But RegReplace is written in Python, which uses backslashes only.